# Selecting multiple values in a column with a specific name with python for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

```
df4=df3[['occ_title','tot_emp']]
df4.loc[df4['occ_title'] == 'Cooks, Fast Food']
```

This code returns the fast food cooks but I am not sure how to select more than one occ_title. I will be using the data to project in a chart.

[The dataframe can be seen in the image and I want to select several "occ_titles" with their tot_emp number as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj8e1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .isin() method?

`df4 = df3.loc[df3['occ_title'].isin(['Cooks, Fast Food','Second, Title']), ['occ_title','tot_emp']]`

Comment: don't chain your indexers like that. do `df4 = df3.loc[<row indexer>, <col indexer>]`